# iPhone - UITableViewCell - Change NIB CustomCell by another NIB CustomCell when select a row?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitableview

I have one UITableView with a custom cell loaded from a nib file, it works fine.

When I select a row(named CustomCell1), It is possible to load another CustomCell2 and replace CustomCell1 with it?

I guess I have to use didSelectRowAtIndexPath() but I don't know how.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use set a "selected" iVar somewhere else, then reload the cell. if it's selected, load the selected nib. You are probably better off having both views in the same cell and swap them with a fade transition though.

Comment: Thanks.

Is easier using two views in the same nib but now I have a curiosity from another nib loading.

Can you give me an example? I do not get it working. Everything you told me goes in didSelectRowAtIndexPath()?

Sry for my english and for my noob question.

Comment: well, the thought is that you would set the cell as selected somewhere in your view controller (say by having a selectedIndexPath ivar). Then you would call [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:. Then in cellForRowAtIndexPath: you'd do if([selectedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]) {
 //load a nib
} else {
 //load another nib
}

again, probably a bad idea.